# Erro ao atualizar form com ImageField

Tags: django

Ao cadastrar um novo registro com upload salva normalmente, mas ao atualizar mostra o erro a seguir:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: Meu formulário]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dei um print na var picture e quando cadastro um novo mostra imagem.png, mas ao atualizar fica diretorio/imagem.png.

Comment: Não use imagens para descrever código ou mensagens de erro. Isso atrapalha a busca por duplicatas e impossibilita a leitura por usuários de leitores de tela.

Comment: Veja se ajuda https://coderwall.com/p/bz0sng/simple-django-image-upload-to-model-imagefield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    def clean_image(self):
      picture = self.cleaned_data.get("image")
      try:
          if picture:
              w, h = get_image_dimensions(picture)
              if not picture.content_type in "image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg":
                  raise forms.ValidationError('Permitido apenas os formatos: *.jpg, *.jpeg, *.png.')
              if w > 200 or h > 200:
                  raise forms.ValidationError('Imagem muito grande, o tamanho tem que ser ' + str(200) + 'px * ' + str(200) + 'px.')
      except AttributeError:
          """
          Handles case when we are updating the user profile
          and do not supply a new avatar
          """
          pass
      return picture
```

Consegui resolver dessa forma.